# LDAP Query to get all Children of OU with all their groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

My LDAP structure looks as follows:

> - DC=test,DC=ldap
>
>   - OU=stuff
>
>     - OU=groups
>
>       - CN=group-1
>           *member: CN=**user-1**,OU=user,OU=stuff,DC=test,DC=ldap*
>       - CN=group-2
>           *member: CN=**user-1**,OU=user,OU=stuff,DC=test,DC=ldap
>
>           member: CN=**user-2**,OU=user,OU=stuff,DC=test,DC=ldap*
>       - CN=group-3
>           *member: CN=**user-2**,OU=user,OU=stuff,DC=test,DC=ldap*
>     - OU=users
>
>       - CN=user-1
>           *memberOf: CN=**group-1**,OU=groups,OU=stuff,DC=test,DC=ldap
>
>           memberOf: CN=**group-2**,OU=groups,OU=stuff,DC=test,DC=ldap*
>       - CN=user-2
>           *memberOf: CN=**group-2**,OU=groups,OU=stuff,DC=test,DC=ldap
>
>           memberOf: CN=**group-3**,OU=groups,OU=stuff,DC=test,DC=ldap*

Can anyone tell me how a Windows cmd LDAP Query has to look like so that I get exactly the following response (maybe more table-like):

user-1: group-1, group-2
user-2: group-2, group-3

Thank you